# Perl script or module like version-control for files in a directory?

Tags: perl, module, compare

I need to update the Oracle's RDBMS binaries. I'm looking for perl script or module that will show me which files have been changed (new, deleted, modified, etc.). I plan to run a script before and after patching, and then compare the results.

I will be grateful for an answer, because Google returns too many results for the "perl compare" phrase.

Best regards,
Scottie

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you could use git and spare you of the hassle. Init a repo in the directory where you want to see this kind of data, commit your changes and then use diffs to compare between them.

I know this maybe is not applicable, and maybe git add or commit will take a long time, but if  it's possible, git will give you a lot of information for free.

If you really want to use perl, maybe you're interested in checking the File::Find module (the walk function) and using stat to get this statistics from the files.

Comment: Good idea with Git (or other DRCS). But, unfortunately it's HP-UX system with a very small set of built-in tools, and I don't have a root account.

Answer (score 2):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Path::Class;
use Digest::MD5;
use Data::Dumper; # Dumper
use Text::Diff; # diff
```

That's the modules I use for a script of mine that does just that (to track ZIP/PDF/CHM in a directory and eliminate duplicates). Use `Path::Class::Dir->traverse` to walk the directory, `Digest::MD5` and `stat` to track file identity (for renames) by not recalculating checksums when file size and mtime are identical (safe enough for my purposes), `Data::Dumper` to load last time's results and save the new ones, and `Text::Diff` to compare text file versions of the old and new data and print a diff as a report. If you want to look at `Dumper` output, consider setting the following options for readability:

```
$Data::Dumper::Terse    = 1;
$Data::Dumper::Indent   = 1;
$Data::Dumper::Sortkeys = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you create a list of files and a checksum for each file, then run `diff` on them afterward?

For example, if you have the necessary command-line tools, you could run

```
find [directory] -print0 | sort -z | xargs -0 md5sum
```

at the command-line and compare the resulting files before and after the patch.  Missing lines correspond to deleted files, extra lines correspond to new files, and changed checksums correspond to modified files.

If you want to use perl, you could write something similar with File::Find and Digest::MD5.